# Specs2 spec fails to compile after upgrade to latest version

Tags: unit-testing, scala, compiler-construction, type-inference, specs2

I have just upgraded Specs2 on my project and now some specs won't compile and it isn't clear why they're not, here's the spec:

```
"fail validation if a connection is disconnected" in {

  val connection = factory.create

  awaitFuture(connection.disconnect)

  factory.validate(connection) match {
    case Failure(e) => ok("Connection successfully rejected")
    case Success(c) => failure("should not have come here")
  }

}
```

(The whole file can be seen [here](https://github.com/mauricio/postgresql-async/blob/3477a01757b7e281ffea70f37ab808325415c58f/mysql-async/src/test/scala/com/github/mauricio/async/db/mysql/pool/MySQLConnectionFactorySpec.scala#L81))

And the compiler says:

> could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type
>   org.specs2.execute.AsResult[Product with Serializable]
>       "fail validation if a connection is disconnected" in {
>                                                         ^

And while I understand what it is saying, it doesn't make any sense given I am returning `ok` or `failure` and I'm covering all cases on my match.

Any idea what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler is trying to find the common type of the 2 match branches. The first line is using `ok` which is a `MatchResult` and the second line is using `failure` which is returning a `Result`. Their only common type is `Product with Serializable`.

The fix is simply to use the opposite value of `ok` which is `ko`:

```
factory.validate(connection) match {
  case Failure(e) => ok("Connection successfully rejected")
  case Success(c) => ko("should not have come here")
}
```

You could also write

```
import org.specs2.execute._

...

factory.validate(connection) match {
  case Failure(e) => Success("Connection successfully rejected")
  case Success(c) => failure("should not have come here")
}
```

There is however no `success(message: String)` method available to match the corresponding `failure`. I will add it to the next specs2 version for better symmetry.